# segmented control - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to use sender to get the value from segmented control, but I am getting the unrecognized selector sent to instance error. The segmented control was added within a view. I've tried removing the semicolon and/or sender and none of the prior posts I've found seem to help. Any ideas?

Swift Code

```
        var segCntrl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Yes","No"])
        segCntrl.tag = 100
        segCntrl.center = CGPointMake(qView.bounds.width/2, qView.bounds.minY+40)
        self.qView.addSubview(segCntrl)

        func segmentorSwitch(sender: AnyObject) {
            if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
                println("Yes selected")
            }
            else if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
                println("No selected")
            }
        }
        segCntrl.addTarget(self, action: "segmentorSwitch:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

Error code:

> 2015-07-07 11:46:24.482 myApp [75641:1855377] -[[myApp.SegViewControllerr segmentorSwitch:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbb0a43b450
>   2015-07-07 11:46:24.489 myApp[75641:1855377] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[myApp.SegViewController segmentorSwitch:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbb0a43b450'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001060dcc65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010838abb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001060e40ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
>       3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010603a13c ___forwarding_** + 988
>       4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106039cd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
>       5   UIKit                               0x00000001070bfd62 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
>       6   UIKit                               0x00000001071d150a -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
>       7   UIKit                               0x000000010724dfba -[UISegmentedControl _setSelectedSegmentIndex:notify:animate:] + 570
>       8   UIKit                               0x000000010724ffbf -[UISegmentedControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 143
>       9   UIKit                               0x000000010710c958 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
>       10  UIKit                               0x000000010710d282 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 682
>       11  UIKit                               0x00000001070d3541 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
>       12  UIKit                               0x00000001070e0cdc _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 18265
>       13  UIKit                               0x00000001070bb59c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
>       14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106010431 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>       15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001060062fd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
>       16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106005934 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
>       17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106005366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
>       18  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010cc5ba3e GSEventRunModal + 161
>       19  UIKit                               0x00000001070be8c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
>       20  myApp                               0x0000000104d9a0c7 main + 135
>       21  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109458145 start + 1
>       22  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like segmentorSwitch: is implemented inside another method. Define it outside the method in which your code is contained, and this should be fixed.